# Why is Hangfire requiring authentication to view dashboard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, hangfire

I am running HangFire within my MVC web app but whenever I try to navigate to http://MyApp/hangfire, it redirects me to my app's login page as though I am not logged in.

I have not explicitly configured any requirements for authorization...e.g. I had the below in the web.config, but then took it out in attempts to get this to work.

```
<location path="hangfire">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrator" />
    <deny users="*" />  
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

In theory, this is what I'd want, and when I log into my main web application, I will be logged in with an `Administrator` role so this rule should work.

But whether I have that configured in the web.config or not, whenever I try to navigate to http://MyApp/hangfire, it redirects me to my apps login page as configured in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="960" />
</authentication>
```

It does NOT do this on my local machine, just when I publish to my host. Does HangFire not recognize the authentication cookie that my main app provides when I login? I thought in general, the hangfire app doesn't require authentication, so what other configuration could be thinking that it does?

**UPDATE 1:**

I added the authorization filters per the [hangfire docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-authorization.html), but the same thing happens. Here is my code in Startup.cs:

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Logging;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using OTIS.Web.AppCode;
using OTISScheduler.AppServ;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Security;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(OTIS.Web.App_Start.Startup))]
namespace OTIS.Web.App_Start
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {

            app.UseHangfire(config => {
                config.UseSqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
                config.UseServer();

                //Dashboard authorization
                config.UseAuthorizationFilters(new AuthorizationFilter
                {
                    Users = "USERA", // allow only specified users (comma delimited list)
                    Roles = "Account Administrator, Administrator" // allow only specified roles(comma delimited list)
                });


            });

            LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new StubLogProviderForHangfire());

            GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });

            var scheduleTasksInitializer = new ScheduleTasksInitializer();

            scheduleTasksInitializer.ScheduleTasks();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Per the more [detailed instructions showing basic authentication](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization), I also tried this...still no luck..redirects me to my app's login page.

```
config.UseAuthorizationFilters(
new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilter(
    new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilterOptions
    {
        // Require secure connection for dashboard
        RequireSsl = false,
        SslRedirect = false,

        // Case sensitive login checking
        LoginCaseSensitive = true,

        // Users
        Users = new[]
        {
            new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser
            {
                Login = "MyLogin",

                // Password as plain text
                PasswordClear = "MyPwd"
            }
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally got it working. I created my own AuthorizationFilter class (see below).
Then I passed that to the MapHangfireDashboard method in the Startup.cs Configuration method (see below that)

```
public class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
        bool boolAuthorizeCurrentUserToAccessHangFireDashboard = false;

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Account Administrator"))
                boolAuthorizeCurrentUserToAccessHangFireDashboard = true;
        }

        return boolAuthorizeCurrentUserToAccessHangFireDashboard;
    }
}
```

To map hangfire to a custom url and specify the AuthorizationFilter to use:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {

    //Get from web.config to determine to fire up hangfire scheduler or not

    app.UseHangfire(config => {
        config.UseSqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
        config.UseServer();              
    });

    //map hangfire to a url and specify the authorization filter to use to allow access
    app.MapHangfireDashboard("/Admin/jobs", new[] { new HangFireAuthorizationFilter() });

}
```

Comment: See @Baris Gomleksizoglu answer for newer version

Comment: It is for .Net 5?

Answer (score 40):

With the newer versions you should use `IDashboardAuthorizationFilter`. With the using statements, it will look like this:

```
using System.Web;
using Hangfire.Annotations;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;

namespace Scheduler.Hangfire
{
    public class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
        {
            //can add some more logic here...
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            //Can use this for NetCore
            return context.GetHttpContext().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; 
        }
    }
}
```

then  in the configuration section:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions() 
      {
          Authorization = new [] {new HangFireAuthorizationFilter()}
      });
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to redirect to a page when user is not authenticated. Ie. to a login page?

Comment: You can achieve it with the standard .net forms authentication:add "authentication" tag to web.config, and check the logged in user inside global.asax inside "FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate".

Answer (score 4):

As designed I believe.
See the [docs for the dashboard](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html#configuring-authorization).

> By default Hangfire allows access to Dashboard pages only for local requests.

Strangely enough I was dealing with this the other day and one thing to be aware of is that if you are using [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) dependency injection then you need to make sure you configure items in the correct order. Specifically Hangfire *after* other authentication but also, in my case, [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/) *before* the other OAuth stuff.
Took quite a bit of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I put that code in and still the same result. I am not using Autofac or OAuth...just basic asp.net basic membership. Any other ideas?

Comment: To all the docs for dashboard do not work at the moment, hope that is just temp issue.Could you please update the link?