# hangfire in docker container not working blank screen accessing dashboard url

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm having hangfire which is hosted inside the docker container. When i try to browse the hangfire dashboard inside the docker container Or locally it is showing me the result. But i forward the port outside and try to access it is showing me blank page for /hangfire dashboard. The application is developed using dot net core.

Dockerfile

```
   FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.1-runtime
USER  root
RUN mkdir -p /LART/WEBAPI
COPY WebApi/Release /LART/WEBAPI/
WORKDIR /LART/WEBAPI
EXPOSE 8082
ADD WebApi/Config/NLog.config /LART/WEBAPI
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LArt.WebApi.dll"]
```

Please find the docker-compose file

```
 lart.api:
   image: lartapi
   restart: always
   container_name: deploy_lartapi
   hostname: lartapi.local
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /WebApi/Dockerfile
   volumes:
    - "logs:/LART/LOGS"
   ports:
    - "8082:8082"  
   networks: 
    lartnetwork:
     aliases: 
      - lartapi
   depends_on:
    - lart.mongo
    - lart.elastic
    - lart.rabbit
```

hangfire dashboard

```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using LArt.Shared;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Mongo;

namespace LArt.WebApi
{
    public class StartUp
    {

        public StartUp(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            //Dataaccess
            services.AddTransient<DataAccess.Interface.IAgentDataService, DataAccess.AgentDataService>();
            services.AddTransient<DataAccess.Interface.ILogDataService, DataAccess.LogDataService>();
            services.AddTransient<DataAccess.Interface.IReportDataService, DataAccess.ReportDataService>();

            //Business
            services.AddSingleton<Business.ServiceInterface.IAgentService, Business.Services.AgentService>();
            services.AddSingleton<Business.ServiceInterface.ILogService, Business.Services.LogService>();
            services.AddSingleton<Business.ServiceInterface.IReportService, Business.Services.ReportService>();
            string[] accessOrgin = new string[] { "http://localhost:8080", "http://lart.web" };
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                  //  .WithOrigins(accessOrgin)
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetPreflightMaxAge(System.TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });


            services.AddHangfire(config =>
            {

                var migrationOptions = new MongoStorageOptions
                {
                    MigrationOptions = new MongoMigrationOptions
                    {
                        Strategy = MongoMigrationStrategy.Migrate,
                    }
                };
                config.UseMongoStorage("mongodb://lart.mongo:27017", "LART_HANGFIRE", migrationOptions);
            });


            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            // loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            loggerFactory.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config");

            //app.useSTatic
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");
            app.UseMvc();

        }

    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LArt.WebApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
               .UseKestrel()
               .UseUrls("http://*:8082")
               .UseStartup<StartUp>()
               .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

docker inspect of the container

```
 [
    {
        "Id": "c83b19fdedf2b03c1bb3e874ba5c9b4c488d250d74013b638fe8626053298853",
        "Created": "2017-09-29T18:52:09.745304871Z",
        "Path": "dotnet",
        "Args": [
            "LArt.WebApi.dll"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 992,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-09-29T18:52:10.443021987Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:b2d196a29aa3069b614dbd6bab4476243c70f6ccd03c35131e1cf680cd05bcb9",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c83b19fdedf2b03c1bb3e874ba5c9b4c488d250d74013b638fe8626053298853/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c83b19fdedf2b03c1bb3e874ba5c9b4c488d250d74013b638fe8626053298853/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c83b19fdedf2b03c1bb3e874ba5c9b4c488d250d74013b638fe8626053298853/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c83b19fdedf2b03c1bb3e874ba5c9b4c488d250d74013b638fe8626053298853/c83b19fdedf2b03c1bb3e874ba5c9b4c488d250d74013b638fe8626053298853-json.log",
        "Name": "/deploy_lartapi",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "lartdeployment_logs:/LART/LOGS:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "lartdeployment_lartnetwork",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8082/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8082"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Name": "lartdeployment_logs",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/lartdeployment_logs/_data",
                "Destination": "/LART/LOGS",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "lartapi",
            "Domainname": "local",
            "User": "root",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8082/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "DOTNET_VERSION=1.1.1",
                "DOTNET_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release/1.1.0/Binaries/1.1.1/dotnet-debian-x64.1.1.1.tar.gz"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "lartapi",
            "Volumes": {
                "/LART/LOGS": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/LART/WEBAPI",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "dotnet",
                "LArt.WebApi.dll"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "e8005c42e4bc420e198d3aac0226222ab6828c55693e41b6903b7f1bbb0ee421",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "lartdeployment",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "lart.api",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.16.1"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "16ceb03a1342f49bb1eb3ff366182b7adb284b7499ffa9635f16b7130facafa0",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8082/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8082"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/16ceb03a1342",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "lartdeployment_lartnetwork": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "lart.api",
                        "lartapi",
                        "c83b19fdedf2"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "4c5da8d914811a140758ded49c7191f05203dddf9a6e77d6f7f2de3af7e827dd",
                    "EndpointID": "b22fa70fba70da2a1610b3d6e08cddea14c8abd5cb9ac218912c6b83f5470243",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Everything looks good as such. When you get page not found is it something from a .NET page or something else? Also I hope you are testing this directly on a Linux machine? if not please explain your setup also

Comment: Yes i setup this in linux machine. when i login to my container using the command docker exec -it deploy_lartapi .bin/bash . Then try to execute wget http://localhost:8082/hangfire. I'm able to see the page serve properly. But when i try to access it from outside page cannot be displayed message is coming

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the browser when the error happens? I am not sure, but hopefully that gives me some idea

Comment: Please find the screenshot of the browser when error happened . It is not page cannot be displayed . It is a blank page. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1vN3_5RjceVZEhzMURCWlA1WTQ

Comment: What does the Google chrome Network tab show?

Comment: This is what showing in the google chrome tab. Any clue??  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1vN3_5RjceVbjRUN2JnOVhPa1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See if this helps https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/04/hangfire-and-asp-net-5/ and https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/hangfire-path-on-staging-machine-throws-a-401-unauthorized/100/6 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441634/why-is-hangfire-requiring-authentication-to-view-dashboard

Comment: Thank you Tarun Lalwani. This link solve my issue. I was not aware hangfire allow only local request if not authorized. Could you please update this in answer section so that I can make this question as answered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155636/discussion-between-vipin-and-tarun-lalwani).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in your screenshot the issue is that you are getting a 401 access denied. The reason being that you need to set `IDashboardAuthorizationFilter`.

See below thread on how to do the setup

[Why is Hangfire requiring authentication to view dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441634/why-is-hangfire-requiring-authentication-to-view-dashboard)